# Autocomplete optimization for large data sets

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, jquery-ui, data-access-layer, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on a large project where I have to present efficient way for a user to enter data into a form.

Three of the fields of that form require a value from a subset of a common data source (SQL Table). I used JQuery and JQuery UI to build an autocomplete, which posts to a generic HttpHandler.

Internally the handler uses Linq-to-sql to grab the data required from that specific table. The table has about 10 different columns, and the linq expression uses the SqlMethods.Like() to match the single search term on each of those 10 fields.

The problem is that that table contains some 20K rows. The autocomplete works flawlessly, accept the sheer volume of data introduces deleays, in the vicinity of 6 seconds or so (when debugging on my local machine) before it shows up.

The JqueryUI autocomplete has 0 delay, queries on the 3 key, and the result of the post is made in a Facebook style multi-row selectable options. (I almost had to rewrite the autocomplete plugin...).

So the problem is data vs. speed. Any thoughts on how to speed this up? The only two thoughts I had were to cache the data (How/Where?); or use straight up sql data reader for data access?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks,

```
<bleepzter/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would look at only returning the first X number of rows using the `.Take(10)` linq method. That should translate into a sensbile sql call, which will put much less load on your database. As the user types they will find less and less matches, so they will only see that data they require.

I'm normally reckon 10 items is enough for the user to understand what is going on and still get to the data they need quickly (see the amazon.com search bar for an example).

Obviously if you can sort the data in a meaningful fashion then the 10 results will be much more likely to give the user what they are after quickly.

Comment: Excellent approach towards autocomplete i was looking like this solution thanks

Answer (score 1):

Returning the top N results is a good idea for sure.  We found (querying a potential list of 270K) that returning the top 30 is a better bet for the user finding what they're looking for, but that COMPLETELY depends on the data you are querying.

Also, you REALLY should drop the delay to something sensible like 100-300 ms.  When you set delay to ZERO, once you hit the 3-character trigger, effectively EVERY.  SINGLE. KEY. STROKE.  is sent as a new query to your server.  This could easily have the unintended and unwelcome effect of slowing down the response even MORE.